select-bluetooth-device not listing all devices web bluetooth api on electron
I'm using electron to list all bluetooth devices (active) around and I want to pick one and connect to it.
My question:
Now, when I'm running npm start, and press the button in the window, the console starts spitting out a few bluetooth devices but unfortunately, not the device that I'm looking for. Does one have any suggestion why I cannot find the device here? Also, no popup is coming in electron that shows those devices, that is right?
Code / setup:
renderer.js:
async function testIt() {
  const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    acceptAllDevices: true
  })
  document.getElementById('device-name').innerHTML = device.name || `ID: ${device.id}`
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click',testIt)

main.js:
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      enableBlinkFeatures: 'Bluetooth', // Enable Bluetooth features
      contextIsolation: false, // Set to false to enable direct access for demo purposes
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  })

  mainWindow.webContents.on('select-bluetooth-device', (event, deviceList, callback) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (deviceList && deviceList.length > 0) {
      console.log(deviceList);     
    } 
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

package.json:
{
  "name": "test_bt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^31.2.1"
  }
}


index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Web Bluetooth API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Web Bluetooth API</h1>

    <button id="clickme">Test Bluetooth</button>

    <p>Currently selected bluetooth device: <strong id="device-name""></strong></p>

    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

preload.js:
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron/renderer')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  cancelBluetoothRequest: () => ipcRenderer.send('cancel-bluetooth-request'),
  bluetoothPairingRequest: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('bluetooth-pairing-request', () => callback()),
  bluetoothPairingResponse: (response) => ipcRenderer.send('bluetooth-pairing-response', response)
})

Extra information:
When I connect to the device using my laptop I get this information:
Driver Name: bth.inf
Class Guid: {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}
Driver Date: 06/21/2006
Driver Version: 10.0.19041.4412
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: BthGenericDevice.NT
Driver Rank: 0xFF2000
Matching Device Id: BTHENUM\GENERIC_DEVICE
Outranked Drivers: 
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: BTH\MS_BTHBRB\6&13dbeec2&0&1

In qT I can also list the device and I can connect to the device like this:
_btSocket = new bluetoothSocket();
_btSocket->connectToService(_btDeviceInfo->address(), QBluetoothUuid::ServiceClassUuid::SerialPort);

node -v: v20.12.2
electron: 31.2.1
npm -v: 10.5.0



From your example it looks like you are trying to connect to a Bluetooth Classic device (a "Bluetooth socket" is a Bluetooth Classic concept), which is not supported by the Web Bluetooth API. Classic devices are filtered out which is why you don't see them in the events delivered to your "select-bluetooth-device" handler.
You should be able to use the Web Serial API using the recently added support for connecting to Bluetooth RFCOMM services: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/serial-over-bluetooth
This should be available in any Electron version based on Chrome 117 or later, which appears to be any of the current stable releases (29, 30 or 31) according to https://releases.electronjs.org/.

Thank you so much! A minor question: as I interpret this page, I cannot use this to search for bluetooth devices and pair them, right? I need to pair them manually? What is the best way to get the descriptive name of the device since this is not in the parameters of the found devices. Like "my Iphone"

You will need to pair the device manually. Descriptive information is not currently available through the Web Serial API.
